# How to include in serialization the id of the recovered objects through the `findAll()` method of CrudRepository in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, serialization, spring-data-rest

I have the following entity class:

```
@Entity
public class GameSet {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String question;
    .......
}
```

Here is my Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface GameSetRepository extends CrudRepository<GameSet, Long> { }
```

Here is the relevant part of my Controller:

```
...
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test/getgamesets", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Collection<GameSet> getGameSets() {
        return Lists.newArrayList(gamesets.findAll());
    }
...
```

And here is the server response:

```
{
    "question": "Choose one of the following, which is wrong.",
    "title1": "MovieA",
    "title2": "MovieB",
    "title3": "MovieC",
    "title4": "MovieD",
    "wrong": 1,
    "explain": "I don't know why this is wrong.",
    "rates": 0,
    "rate": 0
}
```

I would like to get the id of the object in the request result, in addition to the other properties.

Should I override the `findAll()` method?

Thanks for the attention and time!

Comment: It all depends on how you transform the entities to JSON, and also probably on the code of the entity. It has nothing to do with the CrudRepository.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you mean like this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936636/while-using-spring-data-rest-after-migrating-an-app-to-spring-boot-i-have-obser)?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. I don't know if you're using Spring-data-rest and if this answer applies to your application.

Comment: Is this spring-data-rest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just add the following code on my Application class from the previous link:

```
@Configuration
public static class RepositoryConfig extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {
    @Override
    protected void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.exposeIdsFor(GameSet.class);
    }
}
```

And it works!!! Thanks JB Nizet to make me see clear what was my problem!

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49344988/4071001) in case you need to expose the identifiers for all entities, or only for those that extends or implements specific super class or interface.