# How do I expose Ids of a superclass using spring boot repository config

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, repository, spring-data

I have a class called RepositoryConfig.java which extends `RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter`. The class has a method

```
public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration conf){
    conf.exposeIdsFor(SuperClass.class);
}
```

Previous versions of Spring would expose the ids in JSON for all classes that extended the superclass. Now after upgrading to the latest Spring Boot 1.3.2 the id is not exposed for the classes that extend the Superclass. Is there a new way to expose the id for every class extending superclass? Or would I have a line of code that exposes the id for every class that extends superclass?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24938519/794088 might help

Comment: @petey I have many classes that extend a superclass that I want to expose the id for. I am wondering if there is a way without having a line of code for each sub class

Answer (score 0):

You can get all entities through the `EntityManager` and filter them according to your needs:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.metamodel.Type;

@Configuration
public class RepositoryConfig extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.exposeIdsFor(
                entityManager.getMetamodel().getEntities().stream()
                .map(Type::getJavaType)
                .filter(SuperClass.class::isAssignableFrom)
                .toArray(Class[]::new));
    }
}
```

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49344988/4071001) to see other options.