# How to use Spring Data REST and ConversionService using @EmbeddedId?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have an application with Spring Data REST that returns this JSON:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "persons" : [ {
      "personDetail" : {
        "name" : "Alex",
        "surname" : "Red",
        "id" : {
          "group" : "A",
          "subclass" : "1"
        },
        "_links" : {
          "self" : {
            "href" : "https ://localhost:8080/myApp/api/personDetails/A_1"
          }
        }
      }
     }]
    }
}
```

When I go to the url:

https ://localhost:8080/myApp/api/personDetails/A_1

or to this url:

https ://localhost:8080/myApp/api/persons/04ee99a5-1578-400a-84be-d1ca87cda752/personDetail

The app returns this JSON:

```
{
  "name" : "Alex",
  "surname" : "Red",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "https ://localhost:8080/myApp/api/personDetails/A_1"
    },
    "personDetail" : {
      "href" : "https ://localhost:8080/myApp/api/personDetails/A_1"
    }
  }
}
```

The "id" field seems to be disappeared. Where is finished?
How can I do to have the correct object projection?

This is the Person Class:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)", length = 16)
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private PersonDetail personDetail;

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public PersonDetail getPersonDetail() {
        return personDetail;
    }

    public void setPersonDetail(PersonDetail personDetail) {
        this.personDetail = personDetail;
    }
}
```

This is the PersonDetail Class:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class PersonDetail {
    @EmbeddedId
    private PersonDetailId id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String surname;

    public PersonDetailId getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(PersonDetailId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    protected String[] getExcludeFieldNames() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ReflectionToStringBuilder.toStringExclude(this, getExcludeFieldNames());
    }
}
```

This is PersonDetailId class:

```
public class PersonDetailId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "group", nullable = false)
    private String group;

    @Column(name = "subclass", nullable = false)
    private String subclass;

    public PersonDetailId() {
        super();
    }

    public PersonDetailId(String group, String subclass) {
        super();
        this.group = group;
        this.subclass = subclass;
    }

    public String getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    public void setGroup(String group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    public String getSubclass() {
        return subclass;
    }

    public void setSubclass(String subclass) {
        this.subclass = subclass;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append(group).append("_").append(subclass);
        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```

This is the repository REST:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface PersonDetailRepository extends JpaRepository<PersonDetail, PersonDetailId> {

    @RestResource(exported=false)
    PersonDetail findBySurname(String surname);

}
```

This is the Converter that I used:

```
@Component
public class PersonDetailIdConverter implements Converter<String, PersonDetailId> {

    @Autowired
    private PersonDetailRepository personDetailRepository;

    @Override
    public PersonDetailId convert(String source) {

        PersonDetailId result = null;

        List<PersonDetail> details = personDetailRepository.findAll();
        for (PersonDetail detail:details) {
            if (detail.getId().toString().equals(source)) {
                result = detail.getId();
                break;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

And this is the configuration that registers that converter:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomizedRestMvcConfiguration extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    PersonDetailIdConverter personDetailIdConverter(){
        return new PersonDetailIdConverter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureConversionService(ConfigurableConversionService conversionService) {
        conversionService.addConverter(personDetailIdConverter());
        super.configureConversionService(conversionService);
    }

}
```

I used the converter because it's the only way to make working the url:

"href" : "https ://localhost:8080/myApp/api/personDetails/A_1"

Any idea?
Thanks.

EDIT

It seems that it depends by projections.
When I go to the link of the object using the projection that I have created, so the returned JSON contains all the values that I need.

Comment: ia it spring boot,yes, so its doesnt expose ids by default..ref:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936636/while-using-spring-data-rest-after-migrating-an-app-to-spring-boot-i-have-obser

Answer (score 0):

Because of [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/67) where `ResourceSupport.getId()` has a `@JsonIgnore` annotation on it, Spring Data REST will not export the IDs of your entities. You can however rename them e.g. to `personId` (or just rename your getter method).

Also remember to [expose your IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936636/while-using-spring-data-rest-after-migrating-an-app-to-spring-boot-i-have-obser), as Alessandro C mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

From spring 3.1 onwards, this is how to register the converter:

```
@Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
public class CustomizedRestMvcConfiguration implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureConversionService(ConfigurableConversionService conversionService) {
        conversionService.addConverter(new PersonDetailIdConverter());
        super.configureConversionService(conversionService);
    }

}
```