# Spring Not sending all fields in JSON response

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-data, lombok

MY POJO:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.IdClass;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.Data;


@Entity
@Table(name="user_linked_email")
@IdClass(UserLinkedEmailKey.class)
@Data
public class UserLinkedEmail implements Serializable {


    /**
     * serialVersionUID
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Integer userId;
    @Id
    private String linkedEmail;


    /**
     * The Following are appearing in JSON response
     */
    private boolean status;

    private boolean preferredFlag;

}
```

UserLinkedEmailKey class:

```
public class UserLinkedEmailKey implements Serializable {
    /**
     * serialVersionUID
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer userId;
    private String linkedEmail;
}
```

And My Controller Snippet:

```
public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?> getLinkedEmails(@PathVariable(value = "userId") Integer zepoUserId) {


        try {
            List<UserLinkedEmail> linkedEmails = userService.getLinkedEmails(zepoUserId);


            //linkedEmails till this point has all 4 fields

            return new ResponseEntity<List<UserLinkedEmail>>(linkedEmails, HttpStatus.OK);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //
        }
```

Response in JSON is as follows:

```
[
  {
    "status": false,
    "preferredFlag": true
  },
  {
    "status": true,
    "preferredFlag": false
  },
  {
    "status": true,
    "preferredFlag": false
  }
]
```

Why are the other two fields i.e userId and linkedEmail not showing up in response although Spring-Data JPA is returning the entire object from the repository?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Lombok does that.. thus no explicit getter setters.. but for your info, I even tried with removing `@Data` from the POJOs and wrote manual getter setters.. but result is still the same

Comment: sorry did not notice the lombok tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, Spring Data Rest no longer marshalls @Id Properties to JSON.

This can be achieved using expose Ids - Please check [Spring Rest](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/config/RepositoryRestConfiguration.html#exposeIdsFor%28java.lang.Class...%29)

Similar post here with detailed explanation- [id not marshalled to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936636/while-using-spring-data-rest-after-migrating-an-app-to-spring-boot-i-have-obser)

I would suggest to have Intermediate Response Class instead of converting Entity to JSON.

Comment: Also, I would suggest to have Intermediate Response Class instead of converting Entity to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the public getter methods for the class members you want to publicly expose.