# Expose all IDs when using Spring Data Rest

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

I'd like to expose all IDs using a Spring Rest interface.

I know that per default an ID like this will not be exposed via the rest interface:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private Long id;
```

I'm aware that I can use this to expose the ID for `User`:

```
@Configuration
public class RepositoryConfig extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {
    @Override
    protected void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.exposeIdsFor(User.class);
    }
}
```

But is there an easy way to expose all IDs without manually maintaining a list in this `configureRepositoryRestConfiguration` method?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49344988/4071001) to see some useful examples of how to expose the identifiers for **all entities**, or only those that extend or implement a **specific superclass or interface**, or marked with some **specific annotation**.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to do this provided by SDR. [This issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-161) on the SDR Jira tracker gives some explanation as to why this isn't (and perhaps shouldn't) be possible.

The argument is basically that since the IDs are already contained within the `self` links in the response, you don't need to expose them as properties of the object itself.

That said, you may be able to use reflection to retrieve all classes that have a `javax.persistence.Id` annotation and then call `RepositoryRestConfiguration#exposeIdsFor(Class<?>... domainTypes)`.

Comment: There is an example that use reflection (in this case ClassPathScannning)  at http://www.thomas-letsch.de/2015/spring-data-rest-hateoas/

Comment: That being said, IDs are needed especially on headless services and mix and match use cases. there has to be a unique key to point to the object and being interpreted as such on the backend retrieve the mapped object for that unique key. Might as well use the ID itself.

Answer (score 45):

If you want to expose the id field for all your entity classes:

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class MyRepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.exposeIdsFor(entityManager.getMetamodel().getEntities().stream().map(e -> e.getJavaType()).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new Class[0]));
    }

}
```

Comment: .map(EntityType::getJavaType)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as manual configuration would only be possible in the smallest of use cases. Thanks @mekazu this is a thing of beauty! It's working for me.

Comment: .toArray(Class[]::new));

Answer (score 19):

I discovered that if you name the `@Id` field '`Id`' it will display in the JSON if you have a public getter for the `Id`. The Id will show up as a JSON key called '`id`'

For example: `@Id @Column(name="PERSON_ROLE_ID") private Long Id;`

This also works for `@EmbeddedId` fields called '`Id`' as well as long as it has a public getter. In this case the fields of the Id will show up as a JSON object.

For example: `@EmbeddedId private PrimaryKey Id;`

Surprisingly this is case sensitive, calling id '`id`' doesn't work even though it would be a more conventional name for a Java field.

I should say that I discovered this completely by accident so I don't know if this is an accepted convention or will work with previous or future versions of Spring Data and REST. Therefore I have included the relevant parts of my maven pom just incase it's sensittive to versions...

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: The downside to not following java naming conventions is that bean evaluation languages such as SpEL won't easily be able to reference the field.

Comment: Worked like a charm +10

Comment: super find! Id works for me . NOTE: in the json, it only shows as id: 1 , that too at the end of all other fields. "addresses": [
      {
        "custid": "1",
        "address1": "1, stree1",
        "address2": "stree1",
        "city": "city1",
        "zip": "1111",
        "ccc": "ccc1",
        "id": 1,
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/addresses/1"
          },
          "address": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/addresses/1"
          }
        }
      },

Comment: That's much easier than setting the RepositoryRestConfigurer to expose Ids for each class you want.

Answer (score 9):

An updated answer to [@mekasu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47765828/4110190). The `RepositoryRestConfigurer` interface was changed a bit in 2.4.

**Pre 2.4:**

```
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestConfigurer;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.metamodel.Type;

@Configuration
public class Config implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.exposeIdsFor(entityManager.getMetamodel().getEntities().stream().map(Type::getJavaType).toArray(Class[]::new));
    }
}
```

**Post 2.4**

```
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.metamodel.Type;

@Configuration
public class Config implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config, CorsRegistry cors) {
        config.exposeIdsFor(entityManager.getMetamodel().getEntities().stream().map(Type::getJavaType).toArray(Class[]::new));
    }
}
```

Comment: `Type::getJavaType` is which import exactly? Please never omit import declarations.

Comment: `Type::getJavaType` is `javax.persistence.metamodel.Type`

Answer (score 3):

Try this configuration. It works perfectly fine for me.

```
@Configuration
public class RestConfiguration extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter{

      @PersistenceContext
      private EntityManager entityManager;

      @Override
      public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
           //TODO: Expose for specific entity!
           //config.exposeIdsFor(Officer.class);
           //config.exposeIdsFor(Position.class);

           //TODO: Expose id for all entities!
           entityManager.getMetamodel().getEntities().forEach(entity->{
                try {
                     System.out.println("Model: " + entity.getName());
                     Class<? extends Object> clazz = Class.forName(String.format("yourpackage.%s", entity.getName()));
                     config.exposeIdsFor(clazz);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                     System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly. However, RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter is deprecated. I extended RepositoryRestConfigurer class and did override to configureRepositoryRestConfiguration method and write your code as it is. And it's working fine with me

Answer (score 3):

Here is a short solution to expose all ids using only things from springframework:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;

@Configuration
public class MyRepositoryRestConfigurer implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    private Repositories repositories;

    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config, CorsRegistry cors) {
        this.repositories.iterator().forEachRemaining(r -> {
            config.exposeIdsFor(r);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this method to find all `@Entity` classes of the EntityManagerFactory:

```
private List<Class<?>> getAllManagedEntityTypes(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    List<Class<?>> entityClasses = new ArrayList<>();
    Metamodel metamodel = entityManagerFactory.getMetamodel();
    for (ManagedType<?> managedType : metamodel.getManagedTypes()) {
        Class<?> javaType = managedType.getJavaType();
        if (javaType.isAnnotationPresent(Entity.class)) {
            entityClasses.add(managedType.getJavaType());
        }
    }
    return entityClasses;
}
```

then, to expose the IDs for all your entity classes:

```
@Configuration
public class RestConfig extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RepositoryRestConfigurer repositoryRestConfigurer(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        List<Class<?>> entityClasses = getAllManagedEntityTypes(entityManagerFactory);

        return new RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
                for (Class<?> entityClass : entityClasses) {
                    config.exposeIdsFor(entityClass);
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Full working example based on [@FrancoisGengler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55185024/584676):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DataRestApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DataRestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RepositoryRestConfigurer repositoryRestConfigurer(EntityManager entityManager) {
        return RepositoryRestConfigurer.withConfig(config -> {
            config.exposeIdsFor(entityManager.getMetamodel().getEntities()
                    .stream().map(Type::getJavaType).toArray(Class[]::new));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Helped me to get the IDs shown for a specific Entity, by replacing `entityManager.getMetamodel().getEntities()
                    .stream().map(Type::getJavaType).toArray(Class[]::new)` with just `Question.class`.

Answer (score 1):

Following piece of code looks prettier:

```
.exposeIdsFor(entityManager.getMetamodel().getEntities().stream().map(entityType -> entityType.getJavaType()).toArray(Class[]::new))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sharing my solution which is based on [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47765828/330457).

In my case which configures multiple databases, I don't why but, I need to autowire instances of `EntityManagerFactory`.

```java
@Db1 @Autowire
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactoryDb1;

@Db2 @Autowire
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactoryDb2;
```

Now all I need is a method streaming all entity classes gathered from all injected persistence units.

(Maybe, checking the existence of `@Entity` annotation or a custom annotation , say `@EntityRestExposeId`, can be applied.)

```java
    private void forEachEntityClass(final Consumer<? super Class<?>> consumer) {
        Arrays.stream(DataRestConfiguration.class.getDeclaredFields())
                .filter(f -> {
                    final int modifiers = f.getModifiers();
                    return !Modifier.isStatic(modifiers);
                })
                .filter(f -> EntityManagerFactory.class.isAssignableFrom(f.getType()))
                .map(f -> {
                    f.setAccessible(true);
                    try {
                        return (EntityManagerFactory) f.get(this);
                    } catch (final ReflectiveOperationException roe) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(roe);
                    }
                })
                .flatMap(emf -> emf.getMetamodel().getEntities().stream().map(EntityType::getJavaType))
                .forEach(consumer);
    }
```

Calling the `exposeIdFor` method is straightforward.

```java
@Configuration
class DataRestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RepositoryRestConfigurer repositoryRestConfigurer() {
        return RepositoryRestConfigurer.withConfig((configuration, registry) -> {
            forEachEntityClass(configuration::exposeIdsFor);
            // ...
        });
    }

    private void forEachEntityClass(final Consumer<? super Class<?>> consumer) {
        // ...
    }

    @Db1 @Autowired
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactoryDb1;

    @Db2 @Autowired
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactoryDb2;

    @Db3 @Autowired
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactoryDb3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Proabably you can try this to include all id fields. I havent tried it yet, but will keep posted.

```
 public class ExposeAllRepositoryRestConfiguration extends RepositoryRestConfiguration {
    @Override
    public boolean isIdExposedFor(Class<?> domainType) {
        return true;
        }
    }
```

[Excerpt from this link](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-366)

Answer (score 0):

You can add all your entity classes by **exposeIdsFor**. Replace "db.entity" to whick package you put your entities.

```
@Configuration
public class CustomRepositoryRestConfigurer extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        Set<String> classNameSet = ClassTool.getClassName("db.entity", false);
        for (String className : classNameSet) {
            try {
                config.exposeIdsFor(Class.forName(className));
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        logger.info("exposeIdsFor : " + classNameSet);
    }
}
```

The ClassTool is my custom function to get class from given package, you can write by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked perfectly for me ([source here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-161?focusedCommentId=153328&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-153328)):

```
@Configuration
public class RepositoryRestConfig extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(final RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {

    final ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider provider = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(
        false);
    provider.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(Entity.class));

    final Set<BeanDefinition> beans = provider.findCandidateComponents("com.your.domain");

    for (final BeanDefinition bean : beans) {
      try {
        config.exposeIdsFor(Class.forName(bean.getBeanClassName()));
      } catch (final ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // Can't throw ClassNotFoundException due to the method signature. Need to cast it
        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to expose `id` field due to", e);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It finds all beans with the @Entity annotation and exposes them.

Answer (score 0):

Please find a simple solution for this, avoiding to find entities related.

```
@Component
public class EntityExposingIdConfiguration extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        try {
            Field exposeIdsFor = RepositoryRestConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("exposeIdsFor");
            exposeIdsFor.setAccessible(true);
            ReflectionUtils.setField(exposeIdsFor, config, new ListAlwaysContains());
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class ListAlwaysContains extends ArrayList {

        @Override
        public boolean contains(Object o) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yields: `The type RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter is deprecated`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this solution:
- First import [reflections](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.reflections/reflections) library to your POM file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
    <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.11</version>
</dependency>
```

- Then change your RepositoryConfig class to:

```
@Configuration
public class RepositoryConfig extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {
    @Override
    protected void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.example.entity");
        Set<Class<?>> idExposedClasses = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Entity.class, false);
        idExposedClasses.forEach(config::exposeIdsFor);
        return config;
    }
}
```

Change ***"com.example.entity"*** to your **Entity package** and you are good to go. Good luck!