# Is there a way to return association objects with id in spring data rest without Projection

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

I am using spring-boot-starter-parent 1.4.1.RELEASE.

1. Spring boot @ResponseBody doesn't serialize entity id by default.

If I use exposeIdsFor returns the id but I need to configure this for each class

e.g

> RepositoryRestConfiguration.exposeIdsFor(User.class);
>   RepositoryRestConfiguration.exposeIdsFor(Address.class);

Is there a simpler configuration to do this without configuring each entity class.

Refer: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-366

2. The REST resource will render the attribute as a URI to it’s corresponding associated resource. We need to return the associated object instead of URI.

If I use Projection, it will returns the associated objects but I need to configure this for each class

e.g

```
@Entity
public class Person {

  @Id @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  private String firstName, lastName;

  @ManyToOne
  private Address address;
  …
}
```

PersonRepository:

```
interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {}
```

PersonRepository returns,

```
{
  "firstName" : "Frodo",
  "lastName" : "Baggins",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/persons/1"
    },
    "address" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/persons/1/address"
    }
  }
}
```

My Projection:

```
@Projection(name = "inlineAddress", types = { Person.class }) 
interface InlineAddress {

  String getFirstName();

  String getLastName();

  Address getAddress(); 
}
```

After adding projection, it returns..

```
{
  "firstName" : "Frodo",
  "lastName" : "Baggins",
  "address" : { 
    "street": "Bag End",
    "state": "The Shire",
    "country": "Middle Earth"
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/persons/1"
    },
    "address" : { 
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/persons/1/address"
    }
  }
}
```

If some other classes having the association as an address, then I need to add projection for those classes also.

But I don't want to configure for each classes. How to implement the dynamic Projection? So that all my entities will return the nested object in response.

Refer: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-221

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your first question, which was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33171702/5873923),  [exposeIdsFor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/config/RepositoryRestConfiguration.html#exposeIdsFor-java.lang.Class...-) accepts an arbitrary number of arguments. Also, as mentionned [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/520339/5873923) If all your entity classes are located in the same package, you could get a list of your classes using the [Reflections library](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) and feed it to exposeIdsFor().

Comment: Ok. I already tried with this.. it is working fine... Is this a only way to return id in the response for all the entities??

Comment: We can't exposeIds as the class responsible for configuration doesn't know about dependencies packages we plug into the application. Is there another way to include id for nested object ?