# Is it possible to search by association in Spring Data Rest?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

Suppose you have an Entity **User** that has a ManyToOne relationship with **Group**.

How do you search for all users that belong to a certain group?

You can't just create an endpoint with a query parameter like /users?group=1 because in SDR you are forced to ignore IDs and all entities are referenced by their full URL http://host/groups/1

So how do you search by specifying your search parameter?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
@Query("Select u from User u where u.group = :group");
public List<User> findByGroup(Group group);
```

Called with:

`/users/search?group=http://host/groups/1`

Comment: I’m going to test it later but even if it works is this a good idea? I’ve never seen a URL as a parameter in a URL

Comment: You can always expose the id and work with that if you find it better. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30912826/expose-all-ids-when-using-spring-data-rest