# Spring Data REST hides technical entity fields (@Version, @Id) from JSON by default. How to return them as usual properties?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-data-rest

I have a base class

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Data //lombok annotation for getters/setter
public class BaseEntity implements Identifiable<Long> {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Version
    private Long version;
}
```

For any derived class Spring Data REST returns JSON without "id" and "version" attributes.

I found 2 solutions:

1. Projections.
2. Add getters/setters with another names:

   ```
   public Long getRevision() {
       return version;
   }

   public void setRevision(Long revision) {
       this.version = revision;
   }

   public Long getIdentifier() {
       return id;
   }

   public void setIdentifier(Long identifier) {
       this.id = identifier;
   }
   ```

Both solutions look like hacks. Does better approach exist?

Comment: Exposing ids is adressed and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34973156/5873923), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24839760/5873923), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24936636/5873923), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30912826/5873923)... exposing version is addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36853343/5873923).

Comment: Thanks for posting your MappedSuperclass code, it helped me figure out I hadn't added the Data annotation to it, even though it was registered against my entity classes. As of Mar 2020 this was all I needed to add, all the other "exposeIds" techniques were not required, nor did they (unsurprisingly) solve my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Showing the ID of the entity is configuring in the `RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter`:

```
@Bean
public RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter repositoryRestConfigurerAdapter() {
    return new RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter() {
        /**
         * Exposing ID for some entities
         */
        @Override
        public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
            config.exposeIdsFor(MyEntity.class);            
            super.configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(config);
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you! And what about @Version?

Comment: I think you do not need it - the JPA provider works directly with it...

Comment: I want to apply optimistic locking for nested resources. Without version i can only apply If-Match to top-level resource.