# spring data rest export @id xml configuration

Tags: java, xml, spring, rest

I am looking for xml configuration for exporting IDs. By default spring data rest repositories do not export id attribute.

Only solutions i found are configured via java classes.

[Spring boot @ResponseBody doesn't serialize entity id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839760/spring-boot-responsebody-doesnt-serialize-entity-id)

Basicaly equivalent of config.exposeIdsFor(Entity.class) in xml config.

Comment: Have you tried declaring a bean in your configuration file directly. somethign like this `<bean id="config" class="org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestConfiguration">
    <property name="exposeIdsFor">
      <properties>
   <property value="com.pkg.User">
   <properties>
    </property>
  </bean>`

Comment: Yes, i already tried

`<bean id="config" class="org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration ">
        <property name="exposeIdsFor" value="com.pkg.User" />
    </bean>`

and got

`org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'exposeIdsFor' of bean class [org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$594456f2]: Bean property 'exposeIdsFor' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?`

Comment: `exposeIdsFor` will expect list of classes, so you should supply its value inside <properties> as I have mentioned in above comment. Also you should declare bean `RepositoryRestCo‌​nfiguration` not  `Repositor‌​yRestMvcConfiguratio‌​n`

Comment: place this as is `<bean id="config" class="org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryRestCo‌​nfiguration">
   <property name="exposeIdsFor">
      <properties>
         <property value="com.pkg.User" />
      </properties>
   </property>
</bean>`