# Return IDs in JSON response from Spring Data REST

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I've got an entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I initialize it like this

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    List<String> newFiles = this.listFiles();
    newFiles.forEach(filename -> {
        Book book = new Book();
        book.setName(filename);

        dbRepository.save(book);
    });
}
```

If I set the result of `save` to an instance of `Book`, I can get the `id` and it is not `null`—so `id` is created fine.

I defined a repository

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface IBooksRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Long> {
}
```

which I'd like to use to get and set data into the `books` table in the database.

When I try to access my `repository rest` using `curl localhost:8080/books`, I get this response

```
{
   "_embedded":{
      "books":[
         {
            "name":"simple-file.txt",
            "_links":{
               "self":{
                  "href":"http://localhost:8080/books/1"
               },
               "book":{
                  "href":"http://localhost:8080/books/1"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "_links":{
      "self":{
         "href":"http://localhost:8080/books"
      },
      "profile":{
         "href":"http://localhost:8080/profile/books"
      }
   }
}
```

The `books` element returns `name` only. How can I make it return `id` too, on the same level as `name`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring boot @ResponseBody doesn't serialize entity id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839760/spring-boot-responsebody-doesnt-serialize-entity-id)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Spring Data Rest *hides* the ID by default, in order to have it in the JSON you have to manually configure that for your entity. Depending on your spring version you can either provide your own configuration (old):

```
@Configuration
public class ExposeEntityIdRestConfiguration extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.exposeIdsFor(Book.class);
    }
}
```

...or register a `RepositoryRestConfigurer` (current):

```
@Component
public class ExposeEntityIdRestMvcConfiguration extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
    config.exposeIdsFor(Book.class);
  }
}
```

See the [Spring Data Rest documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#getting-started.basic-settings) for more details.

Comment: Hm, there is no method `configureRepositoryRestConfiguration` in `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration`

Comment: Which version of spring data rest are you using?

Comment: Do you know the reason why it is turned off by default? Looks like backbone.js requires to have the id propagated to fully function e.g. collection.get(id)

Comment: Why did you use `@Configuration` first and `@Component` in the other one?

Comment: `RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter` is now deprecated, you have to implement `RepositoryRestConfigurer` directly.

Comment: I saw a answer worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/61279863/2602114

Answer (score 18):

The accepted answer overrides a deprecated method. Here's the updated version:

```
@Component
public class RestConfig implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config, CorsRegistry cors) {
        config.exposeIdsFor(Book.class);
    }
}
```

An alternative approach is to implement `RepositoryRestConfigurer` in your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config, CorsRegistry cors) {
        config.exposeIdsFor(Book.class);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is now a static method `RepositoryRestConfigurer.withConfig` that does the same thing as above. See [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestConfigurer.html#withConfig-java.util.function.Consumer-):

> Convenience method to easily create simple {@link RepositoryRestConfigurer} instances that solely want to tweak the {@link RepositoryRestConfiguration}.

I found the usage in one of [their integration tests](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/master/spring-data-rest-tests/spring-data-rest-tests-jpa/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/jpa/CorsIntegrationTests.java#L51-L60)

So the following approach would be more up to date as of now:

```
@Bean
public RepositoryRestConfigurer repositoryRestConfigurer()
{
    return RepositoryRestConfigurer.withConfig(config -> {
        config.exposeIdsFor(Book.class);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@Component
public class RestConfig implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {

    @Override
      public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.exposeIdsFor(Book.class);
        //config.exposeIdsFor(Library.class);
      }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing! You might want to add a description to your answer with references to make it clearer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for guidelines.

Answer (score 3):

This is a solution which works for all entities

```
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    
    @Bean
    public RepositoryRestConfigurer repositoryRestConfigurer() {
        return RepositoryRestConfigurer.withConfig(config -> config.exposeIdsFor(entityManager.getMetamodel().getEntities().stream().map(Type::getJavaType).toArray(Class[]::new)));
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a good way to go.

```
@Projection(name = "customBook", types = { Book.class }) 
public interface CustomBook {
 
    @Value("#{target.id}")
    long getId(); 
    
}
```

credit: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-projections-excerpts

Answer (score -1):

It was helped me. `Spring Data Rest hides the ID by default, in order to have it in the JSON you have to manually configure that for your entity`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).