# How to always return entity @Id when using JpaRepository?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

Having a `@ReposirotyRestResource` bound to an entity `AppUser` and extending the `JpaRepository` like this:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "users", path = "users")
public interface AppUserRepository extends JpaRepository<AppUser, Long> {

    AppUser findByUsername(@Param("username") String username);

}
```

Where `AppUser` looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "app_user")
public class AppUser extends AbstractTimestampEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    // ..
}
```

I want to receive the `id` whenever I want to `appUserRepository.findUserByUsername("whatever")` - for some reason the default behavior seems to be to *not* return this field.

---

Extra points for either pointing out an error on my side or explain to me **why** this is the default behavior (and a good idea).

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49344988/4071001) in case you need to expose the identifiers for all entities, or only for those that extends or implements specific super class or interface, or with some specific annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is about [Spring Data REST](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/) (you should update tags) - it automatically 'transforms' your repositories to REST controllers with [HATEOES](https://projects.spring.io/spring-hateoas/) where resource ID is the part of included to the resource self link, like: `/appUsers/1`. So by default resource body does not contain its ID.

If you need to include it you can extend [RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#getting-started.configuration) and add exposing ID of necessary classes, for example like the follow:

```
@Bean
public RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter repositoryRestConfigurerAdapter() {
    return new RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
            config.exposeIdsFor(AppUser.class);
            super.configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(config);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Indeed - I found another question on so that faces the same issue. From github issues I can see that this is done in order to make the client kind of ID-agnostic.