# Spring Data REST will export all its attributes (except the id).

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I am currently in learning phase of Spring Data Rest. 
I developed one app in which I was able to succesfully expose the Rest Respoitory but with out the "ID". I searched over the internet to check if I am doing any thing wrong. However, one of the officially links ([Official Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/)) says, **"Spring Data REST will export all its attributes (except the id). You can offer the consumer of your REST service an alternative by defining one or more projections."**
So if have more than ten entities. I have to create ten projections to get it displayed. Is there any other way to achieve it ?

Comment: From a client's view the URI is the ID. There is no need for the database ID.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Data REST assumes the using of [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS), so every resource must have a self reference with its ID. That's why resources don't have ids.

But you can turn it on with `configureRepositoryRestConfiguration` method of  [RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter.html):

```
@Component
public class SpringDataRestCustomization extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
    config.exposeIdsFor(MyEntity1.class, MyEntity2.class);
  }
}
```

More info: [1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr), [2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/config/RepositoryRestConfiguration.html#exposeIdsFor-java.lang.Class...-)

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49344988/4071001) in case you need to expose the identifiers for all entities, or only for those that extends or implements specific super class or interface.