# @GetMapping doesn't serialize Ids

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, spring-boot-jpa

I have a problem with `@GetMapping` in **Spring boot**.

It's about my `@GetMapping` function that doesn't serialize my `id` on this model while getting all data from database:

```java
//User.java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "joined_date")
    @CreatedDate
    private Date joinedDate;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "bio")
    private String bio;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
}
```

I tried many ways but cannot solve at all. Even this question: [Spring boot @ResponseBody doesn't serialize entity id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839760/spring-boot-responsebody-doesnt-serialize-entity-id)

This is the image below:

[image: The ids doesn't serialized in json]

Comment: Please add your controller.

Comment: Here it is: https://hastebin.com/nucajamavo.java

Comment: Please add it to your question instead of a link in the comments. Is that your full entity? It seems to mis getters/setters (and do you have those for the ID?).

Comment: Ahh thank you I solve it(Missing the getter of ID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it! Because I forgot to put the `getter/setter` for the model. And there are more potentials here I wanna tell:

- `private int id` should be changed to `private Integer id` as `@Muhammad Vaqas` told me
- Try to see the solution from this question: [Spring boot @ResponseBody doesn't serialize entity id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839760/spring-boot-responsebody-doesnt-serialize-entity-id)

And there is the full form of the model:

```java
package com.harrycoder.weebjournal.user;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.*;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"createdAt", "updatedAt"}, 
        allowGetters = true)
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "joined_date")
    @CreatedDate
    private Date joinedDate;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "bio")
    private String bio;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getBio() {
        return bio;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public Date getJoinedDate() {
        return joinedDate;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```java
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
```

One solution is to use Integer wrapper class instead of the int. int default value is 0 and Integer's is null.

Comment: let me check more precisely

Comment: `physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl`

Which physical strategy you are using ???

Comment: I don't use `physical-strategy`. What I did it just change the id's data type as you told me. I think you ran the code or debugged the code.

Comment: Yes i had run the code and working fine for me. Do you have git repository for your project so i can reproduce it and help you in a better way?

Comment: And can you please share your JSON response?

Comment: > `Do you have git repository for your project so I can reproduce it and help you in a better way?`

No. Because my project is private. Just let me work on this project privately

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `@PathVariable` in your controller. You can try this:

> Entity:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
```

> Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/users/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<User> getUserFromId(@PathVariable int id) {
    System.out.println(id); // should display the id
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah I put that. Make sure to check the comment from the top of the topic

Comment: The problem is when I run the code and get data from URL(JSON), they don't have `Id`s but my database has. I assure that I add the `@PathVariable` before run the code