# JSON data doesn’t show the id column when running Spring Boot project

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I’m working on a Spring Boot project where I have an entity called “Book” with an id column. I’m using Spring Data JPA and have created a repository interface called “BookRepo” that extends JpaRepository. However, when I run the project and retrieve the book data in JSON format, the id column is not included in the JSON response. For other dependencies I have Lombok, Rest Repositories, MySQL Driver.

Here’s my code for the BookRepo interface:

```
package com.bonglib.springbootlibrary.dao;

import com.bonglib.springbootlibrary.entity.Book;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface BookRepo extends JpaRepository<Book, Long> {

}
```

Here’s my code for the Book entity:

```
package com.bonglib.springbootlibrary.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "author")
    private String author;

    // Getters and setters

    // Constructors
}
```

When I retrieve the book data in JSON format, the id column is missing from the response. Here’s an example JSON response I’m getting:

```
{
  "title": "Sample Book",
  "author": "John Doe"
}
```

I would like the JSON response to include the id column as well. What could be causing this issue? Is there a configuration or annotation that I’m missing?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Not much idea how to go around solving, I had previous tried including

```
@JsonProperty("id")
```

as an annotation but nothing changed.

Comment: What are you using to serialize your JPA entities (directly?) to JSON?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring boot @ResponseBody doesn't serialize entity id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24839760/spring-boot-responsebody-doesnt-serialize-entity-id)

Answer (score 2):

My assumption is you are using Jackson and Spring Data Rest.  By design Spring Data Rest does not expose internal ids, under the principle that internal ids generally do not mean anything to external systems.  Also there is a security argument to prevent internal ids from being exposed.  So by default the entity internal ids (@Id) will be suppressed.

You can obviously change this default behavior.

The most common way to expose entity ids is configuring RepositoryRestConfigurer:

```
@Configuration
public class RestConfiguration implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(
      RepositoryRestConfiguration config, CorsRegistry cors) {
        config.exposeIdsFor(Book.class);
    }
}
```

If you have numerous entities for which you want to expose ids, there is a more generic RestConfiguration that can expose for all entities contained within an EntityManager instance.